# Android MediaPlayer - switch to next song

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player, midi

I generate a midi file and write it like this:

```
File output = new File("exampleout.mid");
```

I think I might need to change this, so it is in the right folder (just a readable/writable folder, perhaps Music/ )

Next I want to play this midi file with MediaPlayer, but I cannot figure out how to load the file.

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test3);
```

Only loads from the read only directory /res/raw. But if I try something like:

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, "file://exampleout");
```

It does not work because create needs an integer as input. I experimented with AssetFileDescriptor, but haven't figured it out yet.

Meanwhile, I want to generate a new midi file and load it in mediaPlayer (chained) to play when the first file finishes playing.

```
MediaPlayer  mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(Activity.this,R.raw.a1);
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new musicCompletionListener());
mediaPlayer.start();
private class musicCompletionListener implements OnCompletionListener {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(WHATTOPUTHERE)
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

My Problem is really how to call the file. I cannot use strings apparantly, and the r.raw directory is not possible due to its read only nature. I feel the solution is not so difficult, but I am just easing into java from c++, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Just a remark. I tried setDataSource(string), but this gives me and IOerror, like described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625680/mediaplayer-setdatasource-better-to-use-path-or-filedescriptor So I guess I need a way like, AssetManager assetManager=Context.getAssets();
AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor = assetManager.openFd("a2.mp3");
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());

Comment: You have to pass Uri in setDataSource which you can obtain as follows.
String path = "path where you are storing your dynamically generated midi file";
Uri midiUri = Uri.parse(path);
Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: @Android_Crazy Thanks. I tried it. It gives me `Uri cannot be resolved to a variable`   on the `setDataSource(Uri)`.   I did it like this: `String path = "/data/data/com.example.optimuse/exampleout.mid"; 
   Uri midiUri = Uri.parse(path);
  
  //String filePath = topDirFile.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "exampleout.mid";
    try {
   mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Uri);
     //mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/res/raw/test3");
  } catch (Exception e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }`

Comment: @dorian I think there is something wrong with the path of the file.i.e the path where you are storing midi file.My suggestion is if you are generating midi files on the fly then do not store it inside your package structure of Application.Store it on sdcard or cache dir of an application.Then try the above code to load the Uri.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stored the file in the cache dir, that works!

```
File output = new File(getCacheDir() + "/exampleout.mid");
```

And then calling the file:

```
    String filePath = null;
    File file = null;
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
try {
           filePath = getCacheDir() + "/exampleout.mid";
           file = new File(filePath);

           inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
           if(inputStream.getFD().valid())
           {
               System.out.println("Valid!");
           }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

       try {
         mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to nicely design the Architecture of your app then only you can achieve what you have asked.

According to me you can do the following.

1. Design an interface with the method midiReady(uri of midi file)
2. This interface is implemented by your activity which contains mediaplayer
3. As soon as midi file is generation is completed call the method midiReady(uri of midi file)
4. Now since your activity implements the interface callback is invoked on your activity and you can set the mediaplayer to play the midi file since in callback you have uri of your midi file.

The above metinoed points are just a faint idea what you can do.With above faint idea you can go forward for implementation.

Hope this will help.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but the midi file will be ready long before it needs to be played. That's why I thought about using onCompletion(). I just don't know a way to play a second file and I cannot find good documentation of MediaPlayer.

Comment: You can implement an queue of midi files as soon as oncompletion is called you can take midi file from queue and play it.

Comment: yes, I think that would work. I am actually stuck at a more basic level, that is, how to call the file (see question). Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You can visit the link http://www.sapandiwakar.in/technical/tutorial-how-to-manually-create-android-media-player-controls/

It tells that we can pass Uri of a file or an external Url to play the media file.Please Check it out.Thanks