# Android MediaPlayer crashes on Prepare()

Tags: java, android, media-player, midi

I am trying to playback a file test3.mid that is generated by the same app and is in the `cache directory` (I have verified that the file is there with filemanager)

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625680/mediaplayer-setdatasource-better-to-use-path-or-filedescriptor) that `setDataSource(string)` can cause errors, so I opted to use `filedesciptor`. The code only gives errors (see below) when I add the `prepare()` method.

Am I making an error somewhere? I see '`NullPointerException`'. Does that mean it does not find the file? What could I try?

I

```
   try {
       String filePath = getCacheDir() + "/test3.mid";
       File file = new File(filePath);
       FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
       mediaPlayer.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
       inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Logcat output is:

```
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.optimuse/com.example.optimuse.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467):    at com.example.optimuse.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:127)
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-25 10:36:44.264: E/AndroidRuntime(31467):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

Comment: did you check if your inputstream is not null? through the debugger..

Comment: i think closing inputStream before preparing must be giving this sort of error

Comment: Also you can perform a file.exists(); to make sure it exists.

Comment: what is there on MainActivity.java:127 line if its mediaPlayer.prepare() statement then your mediaPlayer instance is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely stupid, but I forgot

```
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```