# Android - FATAL EXCEPTION: main, Unable to Start Activity, setAudioSource

Tags: android, audio, recording

I am simply trying to make a basic audio recording and playback activity but keep getting this error.

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.wesle.noisemachine;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReceiveScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button buttonStart, buttonStop, buttonPlay;
private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
private String outputFile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive_screen);

            buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
            buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);
            buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
            buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
            buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);
            outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);

            buttonStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                        try {
                            mediaRecorder.prepare();
                            mediaRecorder.start();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
                        System.out.println("ISE Catch");
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                            System.out.println("ISE Catch");

                        }
                        buttonStart.setEnabled(false);
                        buttonStop.setEnabled(true);


                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });

            buttonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                        mediaRecorder.stop();
                        mediaRecorder.release();

                        buttonStop.setEnabled(false);
                        buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
                        buttonStart.setEnabled(true);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                            try {
                                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile);
                                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("E Catch");
                            }
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording Playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
            });

    //Code for the back button
    Button backbuttonR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backbuttonR);
    backbuttonR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ReceiveScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is the error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.example.wesle.mathsucks, PID: 4255
>                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.wesle.mathsucks/com.example.wesle.noisemachine.ReceiveScreen}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
>                                                                                  at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.example.wesle.noisemachine.ReceiveScreen.onCreate(ReceiveScreen.java:35)
>                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                                  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

And the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.wesle.noisemachine">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.wesle.noisemachine.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.wesle.noisemachine.TransmitScreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.example.wesle.noisemachine.ReceiveScreen"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you provide `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ` permission?

Comment: no, i only did WRITE_EXTERNAL-STORAGE and RECORD_AUDIO, i will try that now

Comment: nope, same error

Comment: Do you use android 6 or above? Permissions are allowed in settings?

Comment: i was using a 5X to emulate, i will try a 6

Comment: still the same error, something is wrong with setAudioSource?

Answer (score 0):

```
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(String);
```

fails,[refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625680/mediaplayer-setdatasource-better-to-use-path-or-filedescriptor) for more info.

so you can use FileDescriptor instead

Create a method

```
private FileDescriptor openFile(String path)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
File file = new File(path);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
return fos.getFD();
}
```

then call

```
 try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(openFile(outputFile));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: That method created a new error:      Error:(37, 30) error: no suitable method found for setOutputFile(File)
method MediaRecorder.setOutputFile(FileDescriptor) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to FileDescriptor)
method MediaRecorder.setOutputFile(String) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; File cannot be converted to String)

Comment: So im pretty sure that outputFile should stay a string

Comment: It cannot resolve FileNotFoundException, im not sure why

Comment: cover it with try catch block